# Calling Java class attributes and methods from Kotlin class

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am trying to access public attributes and public functions in java class, inside a kotlin class. Whenever I try to REPL it using android studio's kotlin REPL, it throws a stub or AndroidManifest error, and when I run it in an emulator, it hangs.

Can someone please provide the right steps to access java class methods and attributes, using a kotlin class?

```html
// Java class start

public class MyJavaClass extends Activity {
    public String myName = "Hello";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public String getMyString(String name){
      myName = name;
      return myName;
    }
}

// Java class end
------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Kotlin class start

class ConversationActivity {
  private val myJavaClass = MyJavaClass()
  Log.d("TEST", myJavaClass.myName)
  override fun replyTo(**some random params**){
    Log.d("TEST", myJavaClass.getMyString("ok"))
  }
}

// Kotlin class end
```

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html

Comment: I have tried all of that, I'm accessing as mentioned in the above documentation, but it keeps throwing a stub or runtime error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE
Java methods and attributes are accessible in a kotlin in the same manner mentioned in the above question snippet.

The reason why they were inaccessible and throwing errors was because they were being accessed from a Java Activity class. These attributes and methods are perfectly accessible from a java non-activity class. As activity classes have protected methods of life cycle, they are not accessible.